# Figure out angle with right triangle in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to calculate the angle of the click i am making in relationship to the middle of the screen. But maybe i am confused on how `atanf` is suppsoed to work.

```
CGPoint pt = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:[touches anyObject]];
    float adj = pt.x - 512;
    float opposite = pt.y - 384;
    float combined = opposite / adj;
    float tan = atanf(combined);
```

but when i try to NSLog Tan, i just get some giant number like `0.1253649`

thoughts?

Comment: How is a number `>1` "giant?" [The docs say](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/atanf.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/atanf) that the returned value is in the range `[-pi/2, +pi/2]`.

Comment: You are aware that the trig functions are all using radians, not degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to convert vector to angle is through `atan2` function:

```
float angle = atan2f (pt.y - 384, pt.x - 512) * 180 / PI;
```

PS: Are you using `cocos2d` engine? It has `ccpToAngle(...)` function.